# Sheaf cohomology vs Cohomology of sheaves

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Do the two expressions "Sheaf cohomology" and "cohomology of sheaves" refer to the same thing or they have different meanings? I'm asking because I read in many texts the two expressions on the same page and I wonder if both are two expressions for the same mathematical objects..

Answer (score 1):

These two phrases are used interchangeably.